# Matlab: interfacing with Windows C++ executable

Tags: matlab, shared-memory

In my team, we are using a high-performance C++ program to read data from the network. We want to place such data in a shared memory buffer in our C++ process for reading in a separate Matlab process that will further asynchronously process the data and provide a display interface.

All this is running on Windows.

What of the many cross-language mechanisms in Matlab is best suited to this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best strategy is to use a [memory-mapped file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/sharing-files-and-memory) to provide data from one component and parse it from another. It appears Matlab's locking primitives are somewhat primitive, but [fully worked out examples](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/share-memory-between-applications.html) are on the Matworks website, including a simple chat application passing data between two Matlab instances.